# ReactJS How to call a function that opens a simple modal?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

My problem might be more related to js syntax, but the thing is, in `material-ui` we receive the js code for the `Modal` function, so how, from another file, does one calls the modal to be opened on a button click (in this case it `onRowClicked` in a table)

The **Modal.js** file with relevant code is:

```
export default function TransitionsModal() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal
        aria-labelledby="transition-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="transition-modal-description"
        className={classes.modal}
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        closeAfterTransition
        BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
        BackdropProps={{
          timeout: 500,
        }}
      >
```

The **MainTable.js** code with the relevant code is:

```
const openPopup = rowData => {
    console.log(rowData.EBELN);
    TransitionsModal().setOpen(true); <---- Trying to call the Modal and open it
}

const MainTable = props => {
    return (
      <div className="col-md-12">
        <div className="feed-toggle">
          <ul className="nav nav-pills outline-active">
          </ul>
        </div>
        <MaterialTable
            columns = {columnsSetup}
            options = {{ NOT_RELATED }}

            onRowClick={(event, rowData) => openPopup(rowData)} -> calls Open Popup

            data={query => NOT_RELATED
                    });
                  })
              })
            }
          />
      </div>
    );
  };
```

Comment: Are you passing the `handleOpen` method as a prop somewhere to your `MainTable`component?

Comment: Nope, going to check how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can try to control the `TransitionModal` from your `MainList` component :

```
const MainTable = props => {
   const [showModal , setModal] = useState;

   const handleModal = status => {
     setModal(status); 
   }


    return (
      <div className="col-md-12">
        <TransitionsModal
         showModal={showModal} 
         handleModal={ handleModal }
        />
        <div className="feed-toggle">
          <ul className="nav nav-pills outline-active">
          </ul>
        </div>
        <MaterialTable
            columns = {columnsSetup}
            options = {{ NOT_RELATED }}

            onRowClick={(event, rowData) => openPopup(rowData)} -> calls Open Popup

            data={query => NOT_RELATED
                    });
                  })
              })
            }
          />
      </div>
    );
  };
```

And in your `TransitionModal` component you just have to pass the prop to control if it will show or not 'showModal' and the method that will allow it to close it `handleModal`, check that ive made one method that can handle open and close, just by passing the `status` parameter:

```
export default function TransitionsModal( { showModal, handleModal } ) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal
        aria-labelledby="transition-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="transition-modal-description"
        className={classes.modal}
        open={ showModal }
        onClose={ () => { handleModal(false) } }
        closeAfterTransition
        BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
        BackdropProps={{
          timeout: 500,
        }}
      >
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, need to define handleOpen and useState. Also I need to pass the rowData to the Modal in order to use another API call.

Comment: `handleModal` is declared at the `MainTable` so you can pass it as a prop to your modal, Also you can pass it any `prop` that you need to the `TransitionModal` so if you need the `rowData` it easy to pass it through components